# RichFaces nested forms ajax components UI render

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have a problem on ajax rendering of UI compoennet
Richfaces - 4.3.2

current code in XHTML:

---form...start 
check box component with a4j ajax event.

---- rich:collapsiblePanel...start
included with another XHTML form having rich:extendedDataTable component.
----rich:collapsiblePanel...end
.
.
mutiple collapsiblePanels.
.
---- rich:collapsiblePanel...start
  another XHTML:
    ---form...start
        rich:extendedDataTable component.
       LightBox Component having another form
     ---form...end
----rich:collapsiblePanel...end
.

.
---form...end

when ajax event happen,
the backing beans are getting updated but when I click on light box, it is retaining and displaying the last viewed report irrespective of what ever record I wish to see.

I have tried a lot of ways, the only solution i got is externally specifying all the form ids in the a4j event render list.

as I am looking out for generic way of doing this with out mentioning all the form ids externally

any help on this would be highly appriciated!

Comment: You shouldn't use nested forms. Can you show the actual code?

Comment: Nested forms cannot be used on one page. Remove form from included fragment. Use `ui:include` and `ui:component` or `ui:fragment`.

Comment: I used h:form tag, the mentioning of nested form corresponds to  rich:extendedDataTable form included via ui:include

Comment: Replace `h:form` with `ui:component` in included file (file with `rich:extendedDataTable`) and check result.

Comment: yeah i have tried that but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah... I could able to resolve this issue:

Remove all the nested forms(i.e., form in collapsible section, light box form in corresponding XHTMLs), introduce a4j:outputPanel in place of removed h:form with ajaxRendered="true" attribute.

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="reportsTablePanel" layout="block" ajaxRendered="true">
```